# Health bar textures move faster than player when camera starts to move from starting viewpoint

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am having a problem drawing a health bar for my enemy textures in the correct position, when the game starts and the camera has not moved and the screen view port:

> FitViewport(GameConfig.WIDTH / GameConfig.PPM, GameConfig.HEIGHT /
>   GameConfig.PPM, gameCam);

has not changed, the bars stay on the enemies correctly, but when the player goes pass half the screen and the camera starts to follow him the bars start to move even if the enemies are not moving.

And when the player gets a certain distance away from the enemies, their behavior is set to arrival and they track down the player also causing the health bars to move further off screen: [here is the health bar off screen when the camera and enemies starts to move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO3RK.jpg)

```
public void drawHealthBar(SpriteBatch batch){
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(wHB,
            (this.getX() * GameConfig.PPM) + 20, (this.getY() * GameConfig.PPM) + 35 ,
            (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 15) * wolfHealth, 8);
    batch.draw(gHB,
            (this.getX() * GameConfig.PPM) + 20, (this.getY() * GameConfig.PPM) + 35 ,
            (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 15) * 1, 8);
    batch.end();
}
```

`wHB` and `gHB` are the health bar texture regions,
does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

Here is the render function in my Play Screen class where the health bar of each wolfbeast enemy is being drawn:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // render map
    renderer.render();

    // render map bodies
    //box2DDebugRenderer.render(world, gameCam.combined);

    game.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
    game.getBatch().begin();
    player.draw(game.getBatch());
    for(WolfBeast wolfBeast: wolfEnemies){
        wolfBeast.draw(game.getBatch());
    }
    for(WaterBlast waterBlast: waterBlasts) {
        waterBlast.draw(game.getBatch());
    }
    game.getBatch().end();

    hud.stage.draw();

    for(WolfBeast wolfBeast: wolfEnemies){

        if(wolfBeast.wolfHealth > .6)
            game.getBatch().setColor(Color.GREEN);
        else if(wolfBeast.wolfHealth > .2)
            game.getBatch().setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        else
            game.getBatch().setColor(Color.RED);

        wolfBeast.drawHealthBar(game.getBatch());
        game.getBatch().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    if(Gdx.app.getType() == Application.ApplicationType.Android) {
        moveButtons.drawButtons();
    }


}
```

Let me know if you need more info and I will provide.
I think the problem is how I'm scaling my world with PPM, can someone please tell me whats going on and how I can fix this?

```
public void update(float dt){
    stateTimer += dt;
    int playerXpos = (int) player.pBody.getPosition().x;
    int wolfBodyXpos = (int) this.eBody.getPosition().x;
    //System.out.println("playerXpos: " + playerXpos + " " + "wolfXpos: " + wolfBodyXpos);
    if (abs(playerXpos - wolfBodyXpos) >= 3.5f) {
        Arrive<Vector2> arriveSB = new Arrive<Vector2>(entity, target)
                .setTimeToTarget(.01f)
                .setArrivalTolerance(2.5f)
                .setDecelerationRadius(100);
        entity.setBehavior(arriveSB);
    }
    else {
        entity.setBehavior(null);
    }

    setPosition(eBody.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, eBody.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
    setRegion(getFrame(dt));
    entity.update(dt);
}
```

Also when I comment out the line that enables the camera to follow the player and the camera doesn't move, the health bars stay correctly on the enemies. It doesn't make any sense, shouldn't the bars only move when the enemies are moving [when camera movement is off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0uJg.jpg)?

Comment: Use StretchViewport if your game having box2D

Comment: Why this line game.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);

Comment: removed that line but still no changes

Comment: Does it work when you remove this line `hud.stage.draw();`

Comment: Can you add the code where you update positions of the enemies?

Comment: The only place a constant like `GameConfig.PPM` should be used is when scaling the size of a sprite (like if you are using your asset sizes to determine in-game object size). If you are multiplying coordinates by a constant like that, you are defeating the purpose of your Viewport class

Comment: @TomGrillGames: It does not work when i comment out hud.stage.draw(); I was also wondering what that means?

Comment: @TobiasG I have added the wolfbeast update and another pic to explain more of whats happening

Comment: @Tenfour04 I was told to / by PPM if you were setting something and multiply by PPM if you where getting something like this.getX(), is that wrong? please explain more

Comment: @TomGrillGames infact the health bar does not render if the hud.stage.draw(); line is commented out or the health bar draw is moved before the hud.stage.draw(); line

Comment: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my projection matrix. I was using a different projection for sprite and a different for body that is why they moved at different speeds.This works best:

```
batch.draw(getFrame(dt),
            pBody.getPosition().x,pBody.getPosition().y,
            1,1,
            1, 1,
            1,1 ,
            0
            );
```

This works for me:

```
public void drawHealthBar(SpriteBatch batch){
    batch.draw(wHB,
            eBody.getPosition().x - .4f,
            eBody.getPosition().y + .2f,
            .7f * wolfHealth, .12f
                );
    batch.draw(gHB,
            eBody.getPosition().x - .4f,
            eBody.getPosition().y + .2f,
            .7f, .12f
                );
}
```

make adjustments to values based on the size of your assets and your scaling